# Sample points between two Bezier curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, curves, interpolation, bezier-curve

I am looking for a way to randomly pick points between two Bezier curves (red and green[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aRIOFf6-zzInadZg3yusyAroXGsAGz4P/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWnMD.png)). I also have a set of points on the two curves and I would like to have an equation that gives me a point between these two curves. Maybe something similar to selecting a random point between two given points.

I hope I was able to convey my point.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The picture you've linked show a lot of special structure: when corresponding control points for the two curves are joined by lines, all the line pass through a common center. The curves themselves are convex (and in particular not self-intersecting), and they don't intersect each other. Are we allowed to assume all these things in our answer, or was that just a convenient way for you to draw the illustration?

Comment: It was just a convenient way for me to draw the illustration!

Comment: OK, so what if each curve resembles the shape of an $\alpha$, and they intersect at, say, four points. What does "between" mean in that case? Unless you make the question well-defined, you can't expect much of an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Not an answer, but I need images to illustrate the point**

The question is, at present, extremely ambiguous. For instance, for the two curves shown here, which of the dots in the figure are "between" the curves? [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer as such, but I try doing this as John Hughes has done to help you to communicate with us what you really desire. You will see below two (cubic) Bezier curves (red and blue), and intermediate curves in between, based on a barycentric evolution. Are you interested by picking a point at random on one of these curves itself chosen at random ?

Matlab program (based on complex numbers representation) below.

[image]

> ```
>    clear all;close all;hold on
>    A1=1+4i;B1=2+2i;C1=3+2.5i;D1=2+0.5i;
>    A2=A1+(1+i);B2=B1+(2+3i);C2=C1+(1+i);D2=D1+(1+i);
>    t=0:0.01:1;s=1-t;
>    for k=0:0.1:1
>       A=(k*A1+(1-k)*A2);B=(k*B1+(1-k)*B2);
>       C=(k*C1+(1-k)*C2);D=(k*D1+(1-k)*D2);
>       plot(A*s.^3+3*B*s.^2.*t+3*C*s.*t.^2+D*t.^3,'color',[k,0,1-k])
>    end;
> ```

Comment: Hi Jean, I am interested in randomly pick up any point on any of these curves. Please, Let me explain my problem a little bit in more detail. I have an optimization problem to find a set of the uniformly distributed (i.e., space-filling ) points between the upper (topmost one) and the lower (below one) curves. Now my search space is defined by these two curves. I am using a meta-heuristic optimization to minimize a space-filling function. To start my optimization I have to generate random points between curves and penalize the point which crosses the search space during optimization.